# How to swap <div> elements by using "mouseover" event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
let wrapperSt = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

for(i=0; i<100; i++){
let divGroup = document.createElement('div');
wrapperSt.append(divGroup);
divGroup.className= 'pixel';
divGroup.textContent= '';
}
```

I've created the div element called "pixel" by using loop because, i need couple hundreds of them. (*I'll use them as a little boxes that could change color*)

But, i want these boxes ("*pixel*" div) to turn brown and sustain (*style.backgroundColor ="brown";*)

So, i created another div that will replace the previous div ("*pixel*").

```
let selectPx = document.getElementsByClassName("pixel");

selectPx.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){

let pxChange = createElement("div");
//This is where i got stuck!

})
```

I could not finish my code, i found it a bit complicated even if it is probably something very simple.

Any suggestions or piece of information would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do... I think you are trying to change the color of the `div` that your mouse is over? If so, you have a couple of issues with your code. Instead of adding the event listener to the list of `div`s, you need to add it to each one individually. Also, you should only need to change the background color of each element instead of creating a new one each time.

```
let selectPx = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");

selectPx.forEach(pixel => {
  pixel.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    pixel.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it worked very well. Appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you have to create a new div inside the first one. In your code, when you trigger the mouseover event you can get the div under the mouse and apply the style to it:

```
let selectPx = document.getElementsByClassName("pixel");

selectPx.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt){

    let divUnderMouse = evt.target;
    divUnderMouse.style.backgroundColor ="brown";

})
```

I haven't tried it but it should work

Comment: Actually, there is no `addEventListener` prototype function to a list of elements.

Comment: @NolanCarpenter you are right, I've copied the original code and I haven't noticed the error